# opening print server using admin account on windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, print-server

In windows XP you can open windows explorer using your admin credentials, but on windows 7 this feature does not work. We need to be able to connect to a remote server to view the printer queue using our admin accounts.

Is there an alternative way to connect using windows 7? Mapping a network drive using different credentials does not work for the print servers.

Are there any alternative programs like FreeCommander that will work for print servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en) installed, you can open the Print Management MMC with administrative credentials (shift + right click & Run as different user). From therer you can view and manage the print queues.

Comment: This seems to only work for those with full control of the printers. We need it for people who only have print access and document management rights. It is for our techies who have access to clear the queue but not alter it.

Comment: Further testing proved that the printer lists were just taking a long time to populate in some cases.